# Node.js date format conversion without using modules

Tags: node.js

Date format conversion without using modules

The following code converts the date into different format: "2016-09-16T04:48:29.250Z"

```
var date = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(date);
```

How do I subtract 14 days and then convert the date into the same format?

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-14);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. Just do:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 14);
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's already a regular Date object then seems like you pretty much had it already:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-14);
console.log(date.toISOString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code

```
 var date = new Date();
 date.setDate(date.getDate()-14);
 console.log(date.toISOString())
```